# How do I calculate some printed text's size in a certain font given DPI of the target printer?

Tags: c, algorithm, language-agnostic, font-size

I have an application that is printing out data to a printer. For now, I have hardcoded the font size as 18 point, calculated all print related coordinates and offsets (for a certain 18 point font) and I'm just printing. I did this just as a basis to develop my application.

Now, I want to be able to dynamically adjust everything (as it should be) according to the font size and face.

I wrote the following test code, without any error-checking, (C) to get the logical size of a font:

```
void GetTextSize(char *input, size_t inputSize, char *fontName, size_t fontSize, SIZE *size)
{
    if(input == NULL || size == NULL || fontName == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        HFONT hFont = NULL;
        LOGFONT lf;
        HDC hdc = NULL;

        memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(lf));

        // Get the device context of the entire screen
        hdc = GetDC(NULL);

        // Set the face-name
        strcpy(lf.lfFaceName, fontName);

        // Set the font height
        lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(fontSize, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);

        // Set the font weight
        lf.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;

        // Create the font
        hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

        // Re-associate the obtained device context with the font just created
        SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

        // Get the required dimensions for the text
        GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, input, inputSize, &size);

        // Free resources
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
        DeleteObject(hFont);
        hFont = NULL;
        hdc = NULL;
    }
}
```

Basically,

1. Get the device context of the entire screen.
2. Create the desired font using [`CreateFontIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [`LOGFONT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.
3. Reassociate the device context with the created font.
4. Calculate the font width in logical units using [`GetTextExtentPoint32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The above code causes the `size` variable to contain: `cx = 241`, `cy = 34`. (My monitor's DPI is 96)

How would I go about mapping these values to the actual printed size? Since the default text mapping mode is [`MM_TEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), these `cx` and `cy` values correspond to pixels.

I need to do this for two reasons:

1. I need to split long lines into multiple lines. Since I know the page width in inches, all I need is the text width in inches.
2. I need to decide where to start printing based on font size.

According to the printer's specs, the dots per mm is 8; i.e., the DPI is about 203.2.

Comment: You might be interested in referring "Programming Windows by Charles Petzold". It has got everything you want. Chapter 13.

Comment: @chux, Why do you recommend tagging to .NET? The code I presented above is in C using Winapi. If anything, I have to add the Winapi tag.

Comment: @chux, What do you mean by "dot height size from the printer interface"?

Comment: @bugsbunny, Thank you for that. Looking into it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already close that what you need.  You'll need to fix a handle leak, a device context needs to be restored before it is deleted:

```
    HGDIOBJ hOldFont = SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

    // Get the required dimensions for the text
    GetTextExtentPoint32A(hdc, input, strlen(input), size);

    // Free resources
    SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont);
    ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    DeleteObject(hFont);
```

What you do next depends a great deal on how *accurate* you want the result to be.  A font that's 15 points on the screen will be 15 points on paper as well.  So if you want to find the widest possible string that fits the paper then you'll get it from:

```
 int maxWidth = (int)(paperWidthInInches * GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX));
```

Note how the DrawTextEx() function can take care of a lot of the grunt work of fitting the text inside the paper.  It takes a RECT that you'd set to the paper size and it will automatically render the text to fit that rectangle.  You typically want to use the DT_WORDBREAK option to get it to automatically wrap the text at word boundaries.  Use the DT_CALCRECT option to calculate page layout without actually rendering the text.  The DRAWTEXTPARAMS.uiLengthDrawn value will be updated to tell you where to start printing the string when it doesn't fit the page.

Now it is just a matter of passing the a printer device context to DrawTextEx() and you'll get the text rendered to the printer.  Pass the device context you get from CreateDC().  The PrintDlg() function is handy to let the user pick the printer.

That was the good news.  The bad news is that GDI doesn't provide *true* device independent text rendering.  Particularly for the monitor, the width of rendered text is subtly altered to fix the pixel grid.  This provides for highly readable text but throws off the layout on devices with a higher DPI, like your printer.  The differences are small, just a handful of pixels on a line of text and the larger the font, the less the difference will be.  And these small differences tend to turn into large differences on the printed text because of word wrapping.

To avoid this, you'll need to calculate page layout by using the printer device context.  Find out where each line ends by passing a RECT to DrawTextEx() that fits just a single line.  What you now render to the screen won't be perfect of course, you'll need some elbow room to render the potentially wider strings.  DirectWrite provides an api for true device-independent text rendering.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I cannot use the DirectWrite API because my application needs to support Windows 2000 and XP as well.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I have to use DrawTextEx to break up my text into several lines, then use it to render each line one at a time?

Comment: DrawTextEx already does this.  It depends on whether you want *easy* or *accurate*.  With the easy way, there's no need to render each line individually, DrawTextEx does this for you.  You only need to figure out where the page breaks occur.  If you want *accurate* then you need to figure out where the line breaks occur on the printer and draw each line individually on the screen to match.

Comment: I just realized that I cannot use the printer's device context to print. This is because I'm dealing with a ZPL printer (Argox OS-2140 DZ to be specific). To carry out my printing tasks, I'm making use of the [APIs that Argox provides](http://www.argox.com/content.php?sno=0000033&P_ID=82). To print some text, the API accepts only the text, the X and Y coordinates (in dots) and the various font parameters. So what I'm trying to do now is to use `DrawTextEx` to split the text into one line, add it to a line buffer, split the next line and so on.

Comment: (contd.) I already have some logic implemented to calculate the coordinates. I had also implemented some flaky logic to split the text into lines until you pointed out this better method. Is what I'm doing necessary or am I missing something again? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If there's a way to find out where `DrawText` broke the string, then that's all I need. I can't seem to find that information.

Comment: It is explicitly in my answer, DRAWTEXTPARAMS.uiLengthDrawn member.

Comment: It is, true. `DRAWTEXTPARAMS.uiLengthDrawn` seems to always store the length of the text *processed*. If I want `DrawTextEx` to tell me where it broke off text to a new line, then I will have to specify a `RECT` of exactly the size of one line. Thank you very much for your answer! It was extremely helpful.